# Implications of imposing strictly positive density for continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am confused on the implications of imposing strictly positive density for continuous random variables.

Take the continuous real-valued random variables $X,Y,Z,W$ **mutually independent**.

Suppose that each random variable has strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$ (in my mind I picture as an example normally distributed random variables). Does this imply that

(a) *any* linear function of $X,Y,Z,W$ (e.g. $X+Y-W$) has strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$?

(b) the function $t(X,Y)+Z-W$ has strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$ for any function $t:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Any example violating (a),(b) would help me to clarify the issue.

I am tempted to say yes  to (a), (b)  but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you assuming that the random variables are mutually independent?

Comment: Should I? Would that help?

Comment: If for example $W=X+Y$ then your example in (a) would fail.

Comment: thanks, let me add independence.

Comment: Several way to view this. In a mathematical way, you may try to use the convolution integral: $\displaystyle f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$ Note that the integrand is strictly positive, so $f_{X+Y}$ is also positive everywhere. Then inductively the whole argument is true. The first step you may need to note is that any location-scale transform still preserve this property. For part b) you just treat $t(X, Y)$ as a single random variable, and if $t$ is surjective, the codomain is the whole $\mathbb{R}$, then it is also true.

Comment: @BGM thanks. For part (b), just regarding $t(X,Y)$: if I assume that $t$ has codomain $\mathbb{R}$ and is surjective, then I can claim that $L\equiv t(X,Y)$ has strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$ even without requiring that $X,Y$ have strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$. Correct?

Comment: Also, for part (a), it seems to me that it may also hold the other way around: if a linear function of $X,Y,Z,W$ involving all the 4 random variables (e.g., $L\equiv X+Y-Z+W$)  has strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$, then each of the $4$ random variables has strictly positive density on $\mathbb{R}$. Correct?

Comment: No & No. Just consider $X$ is normal and $Y$ is uniform, and $X + Y$ has strictly positive density over $\mathbb{R}$ but $Y$ does not.